# Grails 2.4 REST domain with composite id

Tags: json, grails

Thanks in advance for any suggestions. I have a legacy database and having issues in doing list operation with REST JSON.

DB tables:

```
1) vm_properties (to keep key-value properties)
    vm_id int(25) PK 
    vm_key varchar(25) PK 
    vm_value longtext

2) vms table (I guess it should have been vm but as I said it is legacy exxisting db I need to expose CRUD operations using REST-JSON)
    vm_id int(11) AI PK 
    user_id int(11) 
   (.. there are other fields but I guess irrelevant for this problem)
```

Domain classes:

```
1) VmProperties:

class VmProperties implements Serializable {
        Integer vm_id
        String vm_key
        String vm_value

        int hashCode() {
            def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
            builder.append vm_id
            builder.append vm_key
            builder.toHashCode()
        }

        boolean equals(other) {
            if (other == null) return false
            def builder = new EqualsBuilder()
            builder.append vm_id, other.vm_id
            builder.append vm_key, other.vm_key
            builder.isEquals()
        }

        static belongsTo = [Vms]

        static mapping = {
            table 'vm_properties'
            id composite: ["vm_id", "vm_key"]
            version false
        }

        static constraints = {
            vm_value nullable: true
        }
    }

2) Vms:
class Vms {
    Integer vmId
    Integer user_id

    static hasMany = [vmPropertieses: VmProperties]

    static constraints = {
        user_id blank:false, nullable:false
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'vms'
        version false
        id name:'vmId', column:'vm_id', sqlType:'int'
        vmId insertable:false, updateable:false

    }
}
```

Generated controllers:

```
1) vm_properties
class VmPropertiesController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml'] 
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "PUT", delete: "DELETE"]

    def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond VmProperties.list(params), model:[vmPropertiesInstanceCount: VmProperties.count()]
    }

    def show(VmProperties vmPropertiesInstance) {
        respond vmPropertiesInstance
    }
}

2) VmsController - nothing special... looks same as VmPropertiesController
```

I can do /testapp/vms and I get list of vms in JSON. No issues. But when I do /testapp/vmProperties, I get this error: No such property: vmId.... I can see that property is there on that line .

```
    Application starting ... 
    current environment: DEVELOPMENT
    now running in DEV mode.
....errors.GrailsExceptionResolver MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /passfarm/VmProperties
No such property: vmId for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject$Null. Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: vmId for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject$Null
    at testapp.domain.VmProperties.equals(VmProperties.groovy:30)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:176)
    at grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:162)
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:202)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:134)
    at grails.rest.render.json.JsonCollectionRenderer.renderJson(JsonCollectionRenderer.groovy:48)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.rest.render.json.DefaultJsonRenderer.renderJson(DefaultJsonRenderer.groovy:110)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.rest.render.json.DefaultJsonRenderer.render(DefaultJsonRenderer.groovy:91)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.rest.api.ControllersRestApi.respond(ControllersRestApi.groovy:177)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.rest.api.ControllersRestApi.respond(ControllersRestApi.groovy:75)
    at testapp.controller.VmPropertiesController.$tt__index(VmPropertiesController.groovy:25)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: In the `Vms` class you're mapping `vmId` property to `vm_id` field in the DB. Try to do the same in the `VmProperties` class. Rename `vm_id` and map it. There some DBs which do not accept some table and column names. But I don't know which situation you have really.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We are having almost an identical problem using composite keys in Grails 2.4.4